# How to batch update package delays in Altium Designer?

Tags: altium, routing

Altium Designer lets me specify a package pin length and a propagation
delay for each pad of a component.  However, I don't know a way to do
this besides manually selecting each pad and typing in the propagation
delay in the properties window.

I tried writing a script to do that.  Sadly the scripting interface's
documentation is old, probably before the pin propagation delay feature.
I couldn't find documentation on how to access this property.  Ultra
Librarian uses the scripting interface to import their models, but they
don't support pin length or propagation delay.  I guessed about the
method names based on the general naming scheme, but the methods don't
exist.  I was using JScript, if it matters.

- `SetState_PropagationDelay`
- `SetState_Pad_PinLength`

I also tried loading the csv generated by Xilinx Vivado in the pin
mapping popup.  The csv has columns named `Min Trace Delay (ps)` and
`Max Trace Delay (ps)`, but the pads' propagation delay property doesn't
seem to get updated from those columns.

So, how to import package delays into Altium Designer?

Comment: Why don't you ask Altium directly ? They have a quick turn around time on such questions, and you're sure to get the correct reply ...

Comment: @citizen I have yet to have a quick response in 2020. My last issue took 3 months, and it wasn't even complicated. It was just a clarification question. When they used to have phone support - you could get a quick response.

Comment: Sorry to hear, I never have an issue when making contact. Have you recently upgraded ? It does help sometimes. There are also some of the Altium dedicated forums which are worth a try ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select all or some of your pads in the pcb (are you familiar with
  Ctrl-F?).
- Open the PCB List Panel (Panels button, lower right of
  the Altium window).
- Set the mode from View to Edit (Circled in red in
  the picture below).
- Find the Prop delay column.  Select the column,
  Right-click -> Edit (type in the new value).

Same for Pin length.

[image]
AD20.1.14

Comment: All the values can be pasted in at once.  They should be separated by newlines.

Comment: @izmw1cfg Copying/pasting to and from Excel should work as well.  This is useful for keeping everything in order.